# Should [m68k] and [motorola-680x0] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[m68k](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m68k) currently has 18 questions:

> For questions about processors in the Motorola 68k (68000 series) range. Commonly used in Amiga, Atari ST, Macintosh, Sinclair QL and Sharp X68000 computers.

[motorola-680x0](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-680x0) has 8 questions:

> for questions related to the family of Motorola 680x0 processors

Two questions are tagged with both.

Should these two tags be merged into one?  I do not see any valid distinction between the two.

An [older meta question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/470/10260) got rid of the `mc68000` tag, but [motorola-680x0](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-680x0) was created after that meta post.

---

Motorola's official name for the series was `M68000`, which is neither of the tag names.  I feel that `motorola-680x0` is clearer in purpose, even if it is not the "official" Motorola name.  However, the tag usage for `m68k` is better.

Comment: There were quite a number of non-Motorola 68k CPUs that clearly qualify as m68k (Phillips 68070, for example). Thus it might be wise to exclude the company name from the tag.

Answer (score 9):

**I recommend merge to [m68k](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m68k).**

While it may be mysterious to the uninitiated, it is quite clear and common for anyone familiar with 1980s CPUs (e.g., I don't recall ever doing any real programming on anything in the m68k family, but I instantly know what it is.) Google searches for both currently show the [proper Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000_series) as the top result.

Comment: I’ve suggested [tag:motorola-680x0] as a synonym for [tag:m68k]; users with sufficient reputation can [vote up or down on that directly](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tags/m68k/synonyms).

Comment: <https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/> would suggest merging the other way around.

Comment: @user3840170 I still think m68k as the primary makes sense. The key is that tags are primarily for humans - and m68k is more "natural", IMNHO, than motorola-680x0.